# infinite scrolling background - how to make objects move with ground

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, sprite-kit

I have an infinitely scrolling background and a character 'walking' on the ground plane.

I want to drop objects from above and have them land on the ground - so far so good.   But the objects don't move with the ground.

Can't find any examples where this is taken care of.

my 'ground' is just an edge at the correct height with regard to my graphics background.

```
    let Edge = SKNode()
    Edge.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint: CGPointZero, toPoint: CGPointMake(self.frame.width + 1, 0))
    Edge.position = CGPointMake(0, bottomShelf_ItemStartPosition.y)
    self.addChild(Edge)
```

I've tried giving my ground SKSriteNode physical properties, but this didn't make any difference.

What would be the best approach for this?  Must be a simple way to make the moving ground effect objects.

adding scroll routine:

```
    func backgroudScrollUpdate1(){

    back.position = CGPoint(x: back.position.x - scrollPerFrameAmount, y: back.position.y)
    back2.position = CGPoint(x: back2.position.x - scrollPerFrameAmount, y: back2.position.y)

    if (back.position.x < -(back.size.width / 2)) {
        back.position = CGPointMake(back2.position.x + back.size.width, back.position.y)
    }

    if (back2.position.x < -(back.size.width / 2)) {
        back2.position = CGPointMake(back.position.x + back2.size.width, back2.position.y)
    }
```

}

update - some progress

i have set up a physics world, where my ground is infinitely scrolling.  I've got some items that fall out of the 'sky' and land on the ground.  I can move the things around by applying impulse directly or one thing hitting another.

But, what i expected is that the scrolling ground would 'pull' things along with it if they are on the ground?

I have played around with different friction levels of both the ground at the items touching the ground, but it doesn't seem to matter.

one thing that did sort of work is if i set the phsyics body of an item to a circle, then the ground does influence the item, turning it around in the opposite direction of the scrolling - but when it hits an edge it just stops, rather than spinning at the edge.

If that part is working, then why wouldn't a rectangle be dragged along by the ground ?

would love to see example code of a phsyics world that does have the ground effecting other nodes..

Comment: replaced the abused [tag:physics] tag with the appropriate technology tags; please take more care of your tagging next time and good luck :)

Comment: @Adam How do you make this "infinite scrolling background", please add some code to understand what's your issue..

Comment: ok, well the infinite bg scroll is well documented, nothing special. but I will add the routine.

Comment: made some progress: